# ASP.NET MVC - Validation Summary and BlockUI

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

So I've been blocking the page with a "Loading" message using the following code for a logon page

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Log On" onclick="block();"/>
```

If there's an error with the validation though, the block message will stay there forever.
What's the best way to present the block message so it takes the validation into account?

Comment: Could you post some code. Ex. the code the validation produces? :)

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET MVC so all I have to type is @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Password) and it validates based on the model

Comment: As i remember it validates on a pagereload. So how can you fire the validation before the block(); command? Could u paste the code for the block(); command too :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the validation is being triggered automatically and stopping the form from posting, I would simply move the `block();` call to the forms onsubmit attribute:

```
<form onsubmit="block();">
```

This way, it will only trigger when the form submits, rather than when the user clicks the button when the form may be invalid.